Highlight a cell if a another has a greater value than a different cell
I am looking to have cell A1 turn green if the value of A2 is greater than the value of A3. Is there any way to make this happen with conditional formatting?

Select the cell A1 and hit ALT+O+D or ALT+H+L+R --> Click New --> Select the last rule and write --> =A2>A3 and format and use preferred fill color --> Hit Ok Twice!

Oh, perfect. Thank you so much!
